# What does "(\'' + element + '\')" mean?

Tags: javascript, expression

```
function expand(element) {
    var target = document.getElementById(element);
    var h = target.offsetHeight;
    var sh = target.scrollHeight;
    var loopTimer = setTimeout('expand(\'' + element + '\')', 10);
    if (h < sh) {
        h += 1;
    } else {
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        alert("伸縮完成");
    }
    target.style.height = h + "px"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`\'` is an escape character for `'`, so what this is doing is building a string that can be consumed as a function, which contains a parameter, which is wrapped in single quotes...

```
'expand(\''
```

The above portion "opens" the string, applies `expand(` as a literal, then an escaped `'`, followed by one more `'` to close that portion of the string.  So, the return on that is:

```
expand('
```

Next, they concatenate the value of element variable:

```
'expand(\'' + element
```

The string now contains:

```
expand('elementVariableValue
```

Next up is to open another literal string, add in another single quote (escaped), followed by the closing parenthese:

```
'\')'
```

this is evaluated to:

```
')
```

put it all together and you get:

```
expand('elementVariableValue')
```

(which is finally interpreted as a function for the timeout).

Now, with JavaScript, you can use both `"` and `'` for string delimiters, so much easier might have been:

```
setTimeout("expand('" + element + "')", 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Code in your example is a recursive call. It's a timer and the callback is `expand(element)`. Understand this, you can easy understand that `var loopTimer = setTimeout('expand(\'' + element + '\')', 10);` means another call to `expand(element)`. However, function `expand` need a string parameter, so `\'' + element + '\'` it is. Finally, if `element` here equals to `scaleid`, we finally get `expand('scaleid')`, it is obviously another call to `expand()`. Cause it is in string, so `\'` is needed to escape it.

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript you can pass as the first parameter of the function a string, this string is evaluated as if you use eval(). That code is like if you call the function expand("something") every 10 milliseconds.

Comment: This tells him what the function does in general, but based on the question's title it seemed pretty clear he was interested specifically in what that specific syntax was.

Comment: Cool, I will take care about my answers, it seems hard to try answering and get a down vote simply by a not precised answer.